# flowdocumentscrollviewer paragraph visible true false

Tags: wpf, list, flowdocument, listitem, flowdocumentscrollviewer

i have used flowdocumentscrollviewer in one of my application as below,

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer Name="fdsvList" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalScrollBarVisibility='Auto'>
<FlowDocument>
    <List>
        <ListItem Margin="0 0 0 10">
            <Paragraph>
                <Button Content="{DynamicResource CaseSummary}" Name="btnsummary" Click="btnsummary_Click">
                </Button>
            </Paragraph>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem Margin="0 0 0 10">
            <Paragraph>
                <Button Content="{DynamicResource AppDateExt}" Name="btnApp" Click="btnApp_Click" Margin="0">
                </Button>
            </Paragraph>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem Margin="0 0 0 10">
            <Paragraph>
                <Button Content="{DynamicResource PayExt}" Name="btnPayExt" Click="btnPayExt_Click" Margin="0">
                </Button>
            </Paragraph>
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem Margin="0 0 0 10">
            <Paragraph>
                <Button Content="{DynamicResource TsSignup}" Name="btnTSignup" Click="btnTSignup_Click" Margin="0">
                </Button>
            </Paragraph>
        </ListItem>
    </List>
</FlowDocument>
```

My problem is i want to visible/invisible  of the  from C# code.

i can visible/invisible button but i cannot do for  and i have not find visibility attribute for .

how can i do...

please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get answer,

```
listItemcontainer.ListItems.Remove(listItemcontainer.ListItems.ElementAt(1));
```